# How can I access deleted email from Gmail api?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-console-developer

I need to access deleted email in my domain. But I listed users messages from Gmail API, it returns just undeleted emails.

Is there anyway to accessing deleted email body, header ,etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deleted a message permanently, by clicking Delete Forever in your Spam or Trash, you won’t be able to recover the message using the Gmail interface or using Gmail API. An option would be, to file a report to [Gmail team](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/missingemails?visit_id=636929162316097656-1249480328&rd=1).

Comment: Welcome. Hope it helps :)